# Open .sql file SQL Server Management Studio from a folder throught C# with a specfic server name

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I need to open .sql files from a folder using c# . i am using this code to open .sql files

```
string[] Files = Directory.GetFiles(Folder);
            foreach (string File in Files)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(File);
            }
```

this code is working fine but...

**I want to open SSMS in a specific server connection through c#.**

Explanation: I want my c# code to open SSMS in a specfic server connection so that user dose not have to connect to a server when SSMS opens.

Thanks

Comment: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2013/01/08/sql-server-using-ssms-commandline-parameters-guest-post-by-vinod-kumar-m/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use System.Diagnostics.Process to start ssms and send the parameters

```
Process.Start("ssms.exe", "-S (local)\\sqlexpress -E C:\\SQLQuery1.sql");
```

Usage:
ssms.exe [-S server_name[\instance_name]] [-d database] [-U user] [-P password] [-E] [file_name[, file_name]] [/?]

[-S The name of the SQL Server instance to which to connect]

[-d The name of the SQL Server database to which to connect]

[-E] Use Windows Authentication to login to SQL Server

[-U The name of the SQL Server login with which to connect]

[-P The password associated with the login]

[file_name[, file_name]] names of files to load

[-nosplash] Supress splash screen

[/?] Displays this usage information

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6ak8zt5%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

http://zarez.net/?p=1003